# User reputation league site switcher doesn't show the selected site name

Tags: bug, stackexchange.com, reputation-leagues

In the [Stack Exchange user reputation leagues page](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/alltime/stackoverflow), if I select any site in the site switcher it will be set as Stack Overflow or some random site in the drop down list's selected site name.

For the Stack Overflow, Super User, Server Fault and Meta Stack Exchange, the site switcher is set to the selected site name, but the remaining do not retain the selected site name. For English Language and Usage, it changes to Physical Fitness for some reason. All the others I've tried 
switch to Stack Overflow.

It can be replicated in Chrome and Firefox.

GIF for the same:

[image: User reputation league]

Comment: This was soo annoying for me when I was trying to find the top users that were inactive...

Comment: It should be noted that it's currently impossible to use the dropdown to switch to Stack Overflow's top user's list when the dropdown defaults to Stack Overflow.

Comment: It will show the right site if I choose Super User or Server Fault, but the rest of them go to Stack Overflow

Answer (score 11):

In the 6 to 8 weeks this takes to get fixed, you can use the following userscript that solves the bug:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         set selected site
// @namespace    https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/158100/rene
// @version      0.1
// @description  set selected site in league
// @author       rene
// @match        https://stackexchange.com/leagues/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    var url = document.location.pathname.split('/');
    if (url.length >2) {
        $('.fl select option[value^="/' + url[1]+'/'+ url[2] + '/"]').prop('selected','selected');
    }
})();
```

It will select the correct value in the site switcher based on the current league you're looking at.

Find the source on [GitHub](https://github.com/rschrieken/SmallButHandy/blob/master/leaguesiteswitcher.user.js) or directly [install](https://github.com/rschrieken/SmallButHandy/raw/master/leaguesiteswitcher.user.js) it.