# Stack Exchange user reputation leagues drop-down bug

Tags: bug, design, reputation-leagues

when on the [User Reputation League](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/alltime/stackoverflow/2009-07-14?sort=reputationchange) page, I noticed that the drop-down was not functioning correctly. When selecting [Unix & Linux](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/106/alltime/unix/2008-07-31?sort=reputationchange), the drop-down keeps showing Stack Overflow:

[image]

I noticed the same behavior for some other sites, but not all. Even some weird combinations show up:

[image]

Comment: Philosophy shows Pets in the dropdown!

Comment: Movies and TV SE shows Elementary OS SE

Comment: [Not a new bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307227/user-reputation-league-site-switcher-doesnt-show-the-selected-site-name)

Comment: French Language shows Earth Science. English Language Learners shows Stack Overflow....

Comment: It will take 6-8 weeks for SE to solve it :p